# How to restrict units in property shapes?

Tags: linked-data, shacl

I'm looking to make some SHACL shapes for certain properties in my ontology that have a speicified unit. Example:

My instance data would look something like this:

```
otlc:surgeprotector_1
  rdf:type otlc:Surgeprotector ;
  otlc:Nominal_voltage[
      rdf:type otlc:QuantityValue ;
      rdf:value "225"^^xsd:float ;
      otlc:hasUnit unit:KiloV ;
    ] ;
.
```

I then have some shapes to validate this data:

```
otlc:Nominal_voltageShape
  rdf:type sh:PropertyShape ;
  sh:path otlc:Nominal_voltage ;
  sh:class otlc:QuantityValue ;
  **otlc:hasUnit unit:KiloV ;**
  sh:maxCount 1 ;
  sh:minCount 1 ;
.

otlc:SurgeprotectorShape
  rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;
  sh:property otlc:Nominal_voltageShape ;
  sh:targetClass otlc:Surgeprotector ;
.
```

My question: How can I specify the unit given for the predicate "otlc:hasUnit" in the instance data for each property in my ontology? My desired end result is to have a nodeshape for the surgeprotector, and a propertyshape for the property "nominal_voltage", to restrict the value for nominal_voltage to unit:KiloV. I'm hoping there is some kind of shacl keyword I had not heard of/realized I can use here, to add onto my propertyshape (right now, i put in what I would imagine exists for shacl in **). (for example, sh:pattern can be used to specify the value with regex, but I want to specify the value of a piece of metadata of my value, if that makes sense...)

Thanks in advance!
Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can replace your highlighted line with

```
sh:property [
    sh:path otlc:hasUnit ;
    sh:hasValue unit:KiloV ;
] ;
```

This would mean that this property shape must apply to all values of the surrounding property shape, i.e. all values of otlc:Nominal_voltage.

Alternative, you could use a path expression in a property shape one level higher up, e.g.

```
otlc:SurgeprotectorShape
    ...
    sh:property [
        sh:path ( otlc:Nominal_voltage otlc:hasUnit ) ;
        sh:hasValue unit:KiloV ;
    ] ;
```

Note that sh:hasValue also implies sh:minCount 1, i.e. the value must be present. You may want to add sh:maxCount 1 as extra protection.

Comment: Hi Holger,

thanks for your answer! The second option works, but for some reason the first option does not render any results when I try to validate a unit that is not KiloV. 

Perhaps it's something trivial I am not seeing, but my propertyshape now looks as follows:

`otlc:Nominale_spanningShape`
 ` rdf:type sh:NodeShape ;`
 ` sh:path otlc:Nominal_voltageShape ;`
 ` sh:class otlc:QuantityValue ;`
 ` sh:property [`
 `   sh:path otlc:hasUnit ;`
 `   sh:hasValue unit:KiloV ;`
 ` ] ; `
 ` .`

If I then fill an invalid unit in my instances, I don't get any validation results.

Comment: The markdown is not really working, but I hope it's still readable!

Comment: I found my mistake why the first method was not working: Spelling error on my side. Both answers work. Thank you!